# Mocha Multi Reporter with jUnit

Tags: junit, mocha.js

I need to use Multi Reporters for Mocha, so I choose:

https://github.com/stanleyhlng/mocha-multi-reporters

Everything is ok, but I need use custom reporter - mocha-junit-reporter .

How can I use in mocha-multi-reporters mocha-junit-reporter ?

I've tried something like this:

```
"junitReporterOptions": {
        "id": "junit",
        "reporter": "mocha-junit-reporter",
        "output": "../../cms2/raportUnitTestsjunit.xml"
    },
```

But I've got "**Reporter does not found! junit**" . Is it compatible with mocha-multi-reporters ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install "mocha-multi-reporters@1.1.1" to use "mocha-junit-reporter" custom reporter.

```
// File: config.json
{
    "reporterEnabled": "mocha-junit-reporter",
    "mochaJunitReporterReporterOptions": {
        "mochaFile": "junit-custom.xml"
    }
}

$ ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter mocha-multi-reporters --reporter-options configFile=config.json

1..4
ok 1 mocha-test 1 sample test 1.1
ok 2 mocha-test 1 sample test 1.2
ok 3 mocha-test 2 sample test 2.1
ok 4 mocha-test 2 sample test 2.2 # SKIP -
# tests 3
# pass 3
# fail 0

$ cat xunit-custom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="Mocha Tests" time="0.001" tests="4" failures="0" skipped="1">
  <testsuite name="Root Suite" timestamp="2016-10-30T02:27:54" tests="0" failures="0" time="0">
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="mocha-test #1" timestamp="2016-10-30T02:27:54" tests="2" failures="0" time="0.001">
    <testcase name="mocha-test #1 sample test #1.1" time="0.001" classname="sample test #1.1">
    </testcase>
    <testcase name="mocha-test #1 sample test #1.2" time="0" classname="sample test #1.2">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="mocha-test #2" timestamp="2016-10-30T02:27:54" tests="2" failures="0" time="0">
    <testcase name="mocha-test #2 sample test #2.1" time="0" classname="sample test #2.1">
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

You can find a demo project @ https://github.com/stanleyhlng/mocha-multi-reporters-demo

Hope this help!

Comment: what if you don't have a config.json?  I have a mocha.opts file which I'm currently setting my reporter and reporter options in like this:

---reporter mocha-junit-reporter

---reporter-options mochaFile=report.xml

Comment: @stanleyhlng could I also add a HTML reporter ?